# Run 3 async task indepedently in infinite loop

Tags: multithreading, rust, infinite-loop

I have 3 different async methods say `func1, func2, func3` on a struct object.

What I want to accomplish is something like:

```rust
loop {
    obj.func1().await;
    set_timeout(Duration::from_secs(5)).await;
}

loop {
    obj.func2().await;
    set_timeout(Duration::from_secs(5)).await;
}

loop {
    obj.func3().await;
    set_timeout(Duration::from_secs(5)).await;
}
```

I want all these 3 loops to run in parallel. Obviously, in this form it won't work because the 2nd and 3rd loops will be unreachable.

I've thought of the below solution:

```rust
loop {
    thread::spawn(move || async move {
        obj.func1().await;
        obj.func2().await;
        obj.func3().await;
        set_timeout(Duration::from_secs(5)).await;
    });
}
```

But it has 2 issues:

1. My struct does not implement the `Copy` trait (using some 3rd party crates, so cannot do much there).
2. As every function call will run as a seperate thread here, I doubt the timeout will work properly here!

How should I approach this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use an `async` block to create a new future, so if you wrap each loop in an `async` block you'll get three futures.  Then you can use the `join!` macro to await them all simultaneously:

```
let fut1 = async {
    loop {
        obj.func1().await;
        set_timeout(Duration::from_secs(5)).await;
    }
};

let fut2 = async {
    loop {
        obj.func2().await;
        set_timeout(Duration::from_secs(5)).await;
    }
};

let fut3 = async {
    loop {
        obj.func3().await;
        set_timeout(Duration::from_secs(5)).await;
    }
};

join!(fut1, fut2, fut3);
```

The `join!` macro will drive the futures.

Alternatively, your async runtime likely has a way to submit a future as a new independent task, such as [`tokio::spawn`](https://docs.rs/tokio/latest/tokio/fn.spawn.html).